# trouble applying filter to a `.png` image, although the filter works fine with a `.tif` image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, filtering

I have 2 images that I want to apply filter to. The first one is `.tif` black and white and the other `.png` black and white but (I suppose) with a color channel.

Here is a [link to my github](https://github.com/bjce/SO_question_filter) for the images:

here are the 2 original images

`cameraman.tif`:

[image]

`einstein.png`:

[image]

I have no problem applying the filter to the first image `cameraman.tif` with the following result:

[image]

Regarding the second image (`einstein.png`), I have first to read it in a grayscale format to be able to apply the filter at all. But when I apply the filter the image does not change:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from skimage import color
from skimage import io

img =  plt.imread('cameraman.tif')
einstein_bw = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('einstein.png'))

def contrast(img, size=5):
    filtered = np.zeros_like(img)
    H, W = img.shape
    for i in range(size//2, H-size//2):
        for j in range(size//2, W-size//2):
            patch = img[i-size//2:i+size//2+1, j-size//2:j+size//2+1]
            filtered[i,j] =  1.2*img[i, j] - 1/(size**2)*np.mean(patch)
    return filtered

contrasted = contrast(img, 3)
plt.imshow(contrasted, cmap='gray')
plt.savefig('cameraman_contrast.png')

contrasted = contrast(einstein_bw, 5)
plt.imshow(contrasted, cmap='gray')
plt.savefig('einstein_contrast.png')
```

Comment: This might be a display issue. The Einstein image is a lot larger than the cameraman image. Displaying such a large image causes it to be subsampled (pixels are dropped). Thus might explain why you don’t see the effect of the filtering.

Comment: What does `1/(size**2)*np.mean(patch)` mean? You divide the mean vale by the size of the filter? Seems like you end up normalizing twice!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CrisLuengo. So regaring your first comment, I do I overceom the subsampling effect and effectively filter the images? Regarding the second question: I tried wiihout dividing by the size of the filter but the output gets contrasted

Comment: I meant to say that you are filtering the image, but you can’t tell because of the way it’s displayed. “I tried wiihout dividing by the size of the filter but the output gets contrasted” isn’t that the point of the filtering? In the Einstein image you are dividing the mean by 25, in the other image you are dividing the mean by 9. Obviously dividing by a larger number makes the result of the filter less strong.